# IPHONE MPMoviePlayer: Playing video under button layers that can be interacted with while video plays?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I would like to have layers of buttons over video playing in the background on my IPHONE application. Basically, I'm looking to adjust the Movie Player code, in order to allow the application user to tap on different portions of the screen while a video plays and call other commands (for example a video of puppets talking, if you touch one of the puppets, the video pauses and a second (smaller) window appears with a list of information about that puppet; when you exit that list, the video continues where it was paused).

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial explains](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html) how to add subviews to the movie player. However, I don't think that there is a way to programmatically pause a video. In addition, you will still need to figure out which object in the video was touched based on location which seems like the hard part in  this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = ( MPMoviePlayerController * )[ appDelegate moviePlayer ];

[ [appDelegate moviePlayer] pause ];
```